# Is it possible to use the track and follow params at the same time on status/filter stream?

Tags: node.js, twitter

Twitter API Client for node called Twit. I am using twit for my nodejs application to scrape twitter data.

```html
var stream = T.stream('statuses/filter', { follow: twitter_config.handles , track: twitter_config.topics , language: twitter_config.languages });
```

I am using above approach but it doesn't seem to work.
twitter_config.handles are the user-ids and topics are the keywords.

is user-ids correct way of referencing for this architecture???

Should I be using screen_name or user-id???

What to do if i have to use few thousand user-ids and a few keywords??

What about using the same-ip address for entire twitter-scraping application???

Comment: 1. You are using the API. Don't say scrape it means something different. 2. Use ids. 3. You can follow up to 5000 user ids. 4. Bear in mind that it is an `OR` relationship. You will receive a Status object whether the keyword was present or the user id was involved (this includes other users tweeting to your followed user id).

Comment: @TinNguyen,
1. I am using this api to scrape my twitter data, I have provided less in code ( if you require more let me know.)
2. I have used user_ids. 
3. I have used this approach but it doesn't seem to work.
4. How can I get a AND relationship.
This approach doesn't seem to work, can you help me out as to why it is not working.
If you require more details, let me know.

Comment: 1. Scrape, more specifically web scraping means a very specific thing which is usually discouraged. 2. The single line of code you provided says you are using the twitter handle/screen_name, not user id. You also asked whether you should be using screen_name or user id. 3. That was a direct answer as to how many user ids the endpoint is capable of. 4. You will have to write your own filtering logic. The API does not provide this.

Comment: @TinNguyen, can you help me with the filtering logic, if  you are aware about some reference materials that also would be a great help.

Comment: https://github.com/nntin/discord-twitter-bot

this project processes a lot of tweets, is widely configurable (filtering for retweets, user reply, reply to user, keyword and blackwords). It outputs the received Status objects to a webhook.

Comment: @TinNguyen , how can I get AND relationship between user-ids and keywords.

Comment: As I said you have to write your own filtering logic that omits the Status objects it does not apply to. I also provided an example project. I'm not going to help you further.